# JDA List/Collection of SelectOption

Tags: java, discord, protected, discord-jda

I cant create a List or a Collection of SelectOptions in JDA.
I tried it like that:

```
List<SelectOption> li = new ArrayList<>();
    li.add(new SelectOption("", ""));
```

The error message tells me this:

> 'SelectOption(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' has protected access in 'net.dv8tion.jda.api.interactions.components.selections.SelectOption'

I dont know what does this mean and how i fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the factory method [SelectOption.of](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA5/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/interactions/components/selections/SelectOption.html#of%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%29):

```java
SelectOption.of("What the user sees", "id used in event")
  .withDescription("Some description to show below the label")
```